# Bootstrap Navbar on same line

Tags: html, css, django-cms, django-bootstrap3

I am currently trying to create a custom header of a website. It looks like the following:

[image]

Thereby, I am using Bootstrap3 and Django CMS. It looks almost like I want it to, however, the menu should be on the same line as the bottom square. How can I achieve this? The code is the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white;" role="navigation">
    <div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"><div class="square"></div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
        <div class="col-xs-1 blue-bar"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 blue-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Bonus: How can I achieve the blue bar on the right to come closer to the middle square?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways you could modify this (for example, you don't need the first or last `col-xs-1` in the first row -- you can just have the square inside a `col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1`).

But changing as little of your original code as possible, this should work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white;" role="navigation">
<div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10"><div class="square"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
    <div class="col-xs-1 blue-bar"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 blue-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 35.35px; margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

That will put the menu items and the square on different columns in the same row, so they should be side by side.

Hope that helps!